# Using dig to query an address without resolving CNAMEs

Tags: dns, dig

I've pored over the man pages and I'm pretty sure the answer is "no" but is there a way to prevent `dig` from resolving a `CNAME` record for a host?

For example:

```
$ dig +short mail.yahoo.com A
edge.gycpi.b.yahoodns.net.
66.218.84.40
66.218.84.44
66.218.84.41
66.218.84.45
66.218.84.42
66.218.84.43
```

There is not an `A` record for this host, so I should get no answer. It seems like `A` and `AAAA` are treated differently from any other record type in this regard.

I've tried the `+norecurse` and `+noadditional` options without success. I can easily parse the response in my script to see if it has multiple lines where the first one is a FQDN, but it feels like I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Please see the following answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/965368/how-do-i-ask-dig-to-only-return-the-ip-from-a-cname-record

Comment: That is the opposite of what I want. I'm querying for an A record but it gives me the CNAME.

Comment: Ah I see. Well `dig` doesn't indeed have anything to filter it out. You could try `systemd-resolve -4 mail.yahoo.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.html) you can ask for a `CNAME` record type, and if one exists that's what you'll get.

```
dig -t cname +short www.bbc.co.uk
www.bbc.co.uk.pri.bbc.co.uk.
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to ask for (say) an `A` record but disallow lookups through a `CNAME`:

```
dig -t cname +short uk.www.bbc.co.uk.pri.bbc.co.uk    # No output
```

Indeed, [section 3.6.2 of RFC 1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.html#section-3.6.2) writes that,

> When a name server fails to find a desired RR in the resource set associated with the domain name, it checks to see if the resource set consists of a `CNAME` record with a matching class. If so, the name server includes the `CNAME` record in the response and restarts the query at the domain name specified in the data field of the `CNAME` record. The one exception to this rule is that queries which match the `CNAME` type are not restarted.

Per RFC terminology, as there is no "*should*" in this description it is a definitive course of action.

To get the behaviour you're seeking you would probably need to wrap `dig` in some custom code such as this,

```
query=www.bbc.co.uk

result=$(dig -t cname +short "$query" | xargs)
[ -z "$result" ] && result=$(dig -t a +short "$query" | xargs)

printf "Result: %s\n" "$result"
```

Comment: Ah so this isn't `dig` doing the extra lookup, but the responding DNS server. Got it.